# Is this a SQL Server table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone explain this T-SQL statement:

```
select * 
from (select getdate()) as func(param)
```

You can copy & paste the code, and then run it

Comment: What part is it you don't understand? This is quite a simple example of SQL & almost sounds like a homework question. Also, not sure what your subject had to do with this. There is no dynamic SQL in the above statement.

Comment: there is no function or parameter here. just misleading aliases

Answer (score 3):

There is no table valued function or dynamic SQL at all. It is simple subquery:

```
inner query: select getdate()
outer query: SELECT * FROM (inner_query) AS func(param)

func - it is just alias for subquery
param - it is alias for column
```

It could be rewritten as:

```
select sub.current_date_value
from (select getdate() AS current_date_value) as sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner select query is a derived table. Search for that term to lean more. This is functionally identical (no pun intended) to:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS param;
```

There is no need to use a derived table here.